# HQL Query to return the single most recent record, but looking at two (not one) date columns

Tags: hibernate, hql

I have a table for storing items, and wish to receive the single most recently created or updated record.  The table has a 'created' date column and an 'updated' date column.  Of course I could easily separately retrieve the record with the latest created date, and the record with the latest updated date, then compare the two in my code.  But, partly for performance reasons, I'd prefer to do this using the one **HQL** query, and have just the one record back.

I don't imagine this is such an unusual need, but a Google search revealed no online examples that fit the bill.

By the way, here is the **HQL** query I wrote, but it errors.  It's the first time I've ever attempted to use `greatest()` in an **HQL** named query.

`Select m from Movement as m inner join fetch m.vessel as v where greatest(m.created, m.updated) and m.status = 'ACTIVE' and v.id = :vesselId`

Regards,

Chris.

Comment: Do you really have to check both of these dates? Can be created date bigger (means after) then updated date?

Answer (score 0):

> GREATEST function returns the greatest or largest value in a list of
>   values or expressions

It is good start, you can use it for sorting your results and limit query to one result.

```
Select m from Movement as m inner join fetch m.vessel as v where m.status = 'ACTIVE' and v.id = :vesselId order by CASE WHEN  m.updated is null THEN m.created ELSE greatest(m.created, m.updated) END DESC
```

Comment: Thank you Tijkijiki, I like your HQL.  In the interim I created the following HQL, which basically does the same as yours except using the coalesce() function to deal with null values in the 'updated' date column: "Select m from Movement as m inner join fetch m.vessel as v where m.status = 'ACTIVE' and v.id = :vesselId order by greatest(m.created, coalesce(m.updated, '1970-01-01')) desc"